# Xpages: callback in SSJS call to java?

Tags: callback, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a dataView with items task items in order. I let the user move them up or down by clicking on arrows (see below):

[image]

When an arrow is clicked I call a java method with the appropriate params, which changes values in the documents - moving one up and one down and setting the arrow values.

The action on the arrows calls a full refresh, and I can tell that the underlying documents are correct, but the page is not refreshed, or let me say I believe it is refreshed but *before* the java is done. Because I do not see the changes in the view after clicking an error. I see them if I refresh the view from the UI after clicking the arrow.

Is there any easy way to not do the refresh until the data has been updated. Would really like to do a partial refresh just on the data view.

I can add more code if needed.

Thanks.

```xml
<xp:panel xp:key="icon" style="width:35px">
                            <xp:div id="div1"
                                style="display: inline-block;width:50%">
                                <xp:this.styleClass>
                                    <![CDATA[#{javascript:if (entry.getColumnValue("arrowUp") == "Y")
{return "glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down pull-left"}
else
{return "/moveBlank.gif"}}]]>
                                </xp:this.styleClass>
                                <xp:eventHandler event="onclick"
                                    submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
                                    <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:var mveDir:String = "H";
var pckOrd:String = entry.getColumnValue("order");
var type:String = "Inventory";
jc = new com.scoular.model.TaskInventory();
jc.moveTasks(pckOrd,mveDir,type)}]]></xp:this.action>
                                </xp:eventHandler>
                            </xp:div>
                            <xp:div id="div2"
                                style="display:inline-block;width:50%">
                                <xp:this.styleClass>
                                    <![CDATA[#{javascript:if (entry.getColumnValue("arrowDown") == "Y")
{return "glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up pull-left"}
else
{return "/moveBlank.gif"}}]]>
                                </xp:this.styleClass>
                                <xp:eventHandler event="onclick"
                                    submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
                                    <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:var mveDir:String = "L";
var pckOrd:String = entry.getColumnValue("order");
var type:String = "Inventory";
jc = new com.scoular.model.TaskInventory();
jc.moveTasks(pckOrd,mveDir,type);}]]></xp:this.action>
                                </xp:eventHandler>
                            </xp:div>
            </xp:panel>
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new TaskInventory Model all the time during a click? We would need to see java code in order to help.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you need to do the refresh action in the "onComplete" event of the eventHandler.  Assuming you're not coding this from scratch the only way to see the onComplete, onError, etc is to find it in the outline.

Here's a little sample that might help if this is indeed the issue.

```xml
<xp:button value="Cancel" id="button4">
    <xp:eventHandler 
        event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial"
        onComplete="XSP.partialRefreshPost('#{id:mainContent}', {})" refreshId="mainPanel">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.remove("editRow")}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```